# getAnnotations() is empty

Tags: java, annotations

I would like to use annotations in my application. For this reason I create "hello world" for annotations:

follows example:

```
public class HelloAnnotation
{
    @Foo(bar = "Hello World !")
    public String str;

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(HelloAnnotation.class.getField("str").getAnnotations().length);
    }
}
```

And this is the Annotation:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Foo
{
    public String doTestTarget();
}
```

My problem is now that getAnnotations() in main is empty. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Well, one problem is that you use an annotation named `@Foo`, but you define an annotation called `@Test_Target`. It's usually best if you post code that compiles (although *David Grant* gave you the answer anyway).

Comment: Yes sure, thx, I edit it already. That was copy and paste mistake :)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Add the following to your annotation:

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
```

From the javadoc for [@Retention](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html):

> the retention policy defaults to `RetentionPolicy.CLASS`

From the javadoc for [RetentionPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html):

- `CLASS`

  - Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but **need not be retained by the VM at run time**.
- `RUNTIME`

  - Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so **they may be read reflectively**.
- `SOURCE`

  - Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.